# Testing the population mean

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Given a population size and a sample, how can i test if the population mean is above a certain value?

Similarly, can i find out what what value the sample mean has to be to say that the population mean is above a certain value?

Comment: What do you know about hypothesis testing? And "what value the sample mean has to be to say that the population mean is above a certain value" no you can't say that but given a sample mean, you can say that population mean is above $x$ with probability $p$. You know how to find confidence intervals?

Comment: Very little I'm afraid. I understand that confidence intervals is the probability that the population mean lies within the interval, but i want to test if the population mean is above xx

Comment: @AkmalFaiz unfortunately opening statistics calsses just dump formulae and expect you to plug in numbers. They never say why they work the way they do. Perhaps post the book giving you trouble or a page?

Comment: What do you mean by 'find'? If your 'find' is the same as my 'find', you cannot 'find' whether population mean is above or below anything. You can only say with probabilities that it is above or below something.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty yeah let's say i wanted to test if my population mean is above _x_ with a 95% confidence level. what test should i be using? and can i manipulate this test to find out what my sample mean should be to say with 95% confidence that my population mean is above _x_?

Comment: Yes you can. Regarding what test you should be using, you know how to find confidence intervals or that is what you want to know. Whichever case, check out this : http://onlinestatbook.com/2/estimation/mean.html I hope it will help you.